# [Wix Bundle Managed Bootstrapper]Error 0x80070002: Failed to create the managed bootstrapper application

Tags: .net, wix, bootstrapper

I am creating a custom installer with Managed Bootstrapper application. Here I am facing this issue while installation "Failed to create the managed bootstrapper application". I researched about this and found that .net framework dependency is the real issue, but in my machine OS is Windows 10(.Net 4.6.1) and .net framework is installed by default. Error part in log file is attached [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqh0I.png).

Comment: From memory this error can happen in a whole bunch of different cases. `0x80070002` corresponds to `FILE_NOT_FOUND`, so I'd double check that paths etc.. are correct. Maybe also take a look at [Burn custom managed UI not starting](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Burn-custom-managed-UI-not-starting-td7580023.html)

Comment: @Justin Thank you for the link. After checking the link I checked all my application names, it was different than mentioned in BootstrapperCore.config. I changed the name and now its working perfect.

Answer (score 1):

It was application name issue which was changed by mistake. It was a mistake from my side. Now the wix managed bootstrapper application is good.